# Laravel Restful Resource controller & restangular

Tags: angularjs, rest, controller, laravel-5.1, restangular

We have a *Laravel 5.1* Restful Resource Controller (Let's say FooController) with all methods using route

> api/foo/6/edit

We also have an *Angular.js* front-end app which uses *restangular* module to communicate with back-end.

However, when we try to post the data provided by the form to back-end; restangular sends the [PUT] request to:

> /api/foo/6/edit/6

**How** can we modify the behaviour to change the PUT request url to '**/api/foo/6**' instead of '**/api/foo/6/edit/6**' while still using the edit route to get the edit data?

Here is the code used to get the edit data and update the changes:

Code:

```
find: function(id) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    Restangular.one('foo', 6).one('edit').get().then(function(response) {
        defer.resolve(response);
    };

    return defer.promise;
},
save: function(data) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    Restangular.all('foo').post(data).then(function(response) {
        defer.resolve(response);
    };
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Custom PUT instead solved the problem.

```
update: function(data) {
   var defer = $q.defer();
   Restangular.one('foo', 6).customPUT(data).then(function(response) {
       defer.resolve(response);
     }
   );

   return defer.promise;
}
```